# Loading images in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I'm in a documentclass in LaTeX. How do I load an image saved as a .png file?

Answer (score 17):

If you work with `pdflatex` (direct compilation to pdf), you can use the `graphicx` package using the `\includegraphics` command. If your image is called `foo.png`, you can add the following command inside your document.

```
\includegraphics{foo}
```

However, if you work with `latex` (compilation into dvi first), you cannot use 'png' file as image (with any package). You have to convert your image into 'eps' first. If your image is called `foo.png`, then you can convert it with any graphics software into `foo.eps`, and use the following command to include the image.

```
\includegraphics{foo}
```

Here is a complete example with width specification:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
Here is my image.
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{foo}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

Use the `graphicx` package (included in most LaTeX distributions), which lets you:

```
\includegraphics[width=3in]{foo.png}
```

See [an example page](http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/reference/figures.html) to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

I am not using pdflatex. On Ubuntu, I use the `convert` command, that comes with imagemagick, to convert from .png to .eps, and then use `includegraphics`.